# How to get recognized as connected when using file_get_contents(<url>) where <url> addresses a site where I'm already connected via my browser?

Tags: php, authentication, cross-domain

CONTEXT:
On an external site where I have my own account, I can always sign in as usual.
I want to automatize a survey about some data in this site.
So I had to programmatically load the involved page, and I would like to use javascript to look for the interesting data.

PROBLEM 1 (solved):
But if I simply load the page in an iframe (or in a pop window) it results in a cross-domain issue, and I can't access the page contents.
This is normal, so I worked around with the well known solution: use PHP `file_get_contents()` to load the HTML code as a string, where I can look for anything I want.
This is what I'm already using successfully with one site.

PROBLEM 2:
Now I want to do the same, in the same conditions, on another site.
But this one returns its connection page rather the page I asked!
Clearly, when the call comes from `file_get_contents()` the site sees me as not connected, while it sees me connected when I directly call the page with my browser.

So how could I be seen as connected?
BTW I don't understand what causes the different behaviour between the two sites.
When it works fine, I thought it recognized me from my IP; so what when it doesn't?

I tried calling the page with the antique `https://myIdent:myPassword@theSite...` but it doesn't work better.
I also considered I could programmatically dialog to sign in, but I wonder how to really do it.

Is there a mean to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> BTW I don't understand what
>   causes the different behaviour between the two sites. When it works
>   fine, I thought it recognized me from my IP; so what when it doesn't?

It does not recognize you from your IP, it recognizes you from your session, which belongs exclusively to the browser application. I.e., you sign in via the browser, the remote site gives the browser a session cookie, and on each subsequent request, the browser provides the cookie back to the remote site to prove it's logged in. Your calls to `file_get_contents()` do have have access to this cookie, and are thus treated as not logged in.

You can (possibly) accomplish what you want by using [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl) with a cookie jar, and making two requests -- one hit to the login page with your credentials (which provides a cookie that you store in the jar) and then a second hit to the page you want to scrape (which offers the contents of the cookie jar.) See [curl_setopt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options.

Basically, you want to create a curl connection with both the cookiejar and the cookiefile pointing to the same file. Thus, any cookies you receive will be saved, and any subsequent requests you make will offer the saved cookies.

Note however, this depends on the site being coded in a way to allow this sort of request. If the site uses CAPTCHA or CSRF on the login page to prevent scripting, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precise answer. I have to look at it with much attention to understand the workaround and try it. 
But meantime I wonder: why does it work easy with another site?